# Pause/stop publish/subscribe while inserting in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I insert many documents in a method in Meteor. Can I pause subscriptions until this method is finished?

I use https://github.com/mikowals/batch-insert to insert multiple docs and it works fine but the server runs out of memory when trying to publish all the docs while inserting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suppose you should re-think whether you want to publish that many documents: they are all transferred to *each* client and cause big traffic. Also I doubt that the server will not run out of memory if you "pause" publishing.

If you do want that, there is an easy way to pause publishing: pass a boolean parameter from your subscription to your publication and make the subscription reactively re-run when the batch insert is triggered by a client action. Sounds complicated, is easy:

```
// on the client
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    // reactively depend on event causing batch insert
    var doPublish = reactiveVarTrueIfBatchInsert.get();
    Meteor.subscribe('myPub', doPublish, function() { // ... });
});
...
// inside some event
reactiveVarTrueIfBatchInsert.set(true);
Meteor.defer(function() {
    Meteor.call('batchInsertMethod', function() {
        reactiveVarTrueIfBatchInsert.set(false);
    });
});

// on the server
Meteor.publish('myPub', function() {
    var doPublish = arguments[0];
    var result = [];
    if(doPublish) result = myDocs.find({});
    return result;
});
```

The key idea is that `reactiveVarTrueIfBatchInsert` is a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) that is true if and only if you are currently batch inserting.
NOTE: using the wrapper with `Meteor.defer` is essential as without it the reactive variable will not have time to affect the subscription before the method call.